# DDD - transient validation using an aggregate

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

I have a particular scenario where an aggregate has behavior to check whether an address is valid.  This validation is triggered on the aggregate via inline ajax form validation on a web site.  In between the aggregate and the web site is an application service which orchestrates the two.

As it stands, I create what is essentially an empty aggregate and set the address property so the check can be done.  Based on this I return true or false back to the web site (ASP.NET MVC).  This doesn't seem like the right approach on the context of DDD.

```
    public bool IsAddressAvailable(string address)
    {
        var aggregate = new Aggregate
                             {
                                 Address = address
                             };
        return aggregate.IsAddressValid();
    }
```

What options do I have that would work better using DDD?  I was consider separating it out into a domain service.  Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the nature of your validation? Merely checking the format? Verifying it against an address databases? Checking no existing address is registered in your system?

Comment: All of those.  I have simplified the above example. In reality there is also another service being called as part of the validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally your aggregates should not expose `Get-` methods, you always want to follow Tell-Don't-Ask principle. 
If something needs to be *done* - then you call an aggregate method and it makes it done.

But you normally don't want to ask Aggregate if the data is valid or not. Especially if you already have a service that does this job for you, why mixing this "validation" with aggregates?

The rule of thumb is:

- If something is not needed for Aggregate's behavior it doesn't need to be a part of the aggregate
- You only pass valid data into your domain. It means that when you call an aggregate behavior asking it to do something for you, the data you pass is already validated. You don't want to pollute your domain with data validation / if-else branches, etc. Keep it straight and simple.

In your case, as far as I understand, you only need to validate user's input, so you don't need to bother your domain to do it for two reasons:

1. You don't *do* anything, don't change system's state. It is considered to be a "read" operation, do it straightforward (call your service, validate against some tables, etc)
2. You cannot rely on validation result. Now it tells you "correct" and in 10 milliseconds (while you get the response over the wire, while HTML is rendered in browser, etc) it is already a history, it MAY change any time. So this validation is just a guidance, no more.

Therefore if you only need "read-only" validation just do it against your service.
If you need to validate user's data as a part of operation then do it *before* you call the domain (perhaps in your command handler).
And be aware of racing conditions (DB unique constraints can help).

You should also consider reading this to think deeper about set validation: http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/